# Jupyter Notebook Python error: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tuples

I am getting this error so can anyone please tell me how to solve it?

Thank You :)

Code:

```
X_test=np.reshape(X_test,(X_test.shape,X_test.shape[1], 1))
predicted_closing_price=lstm_model.predict(X_test)
predicted_closing_price=scaler.inverse_transform(predicted_closing_price)
```

Error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-f81336c9a6c0> in <module>
----> 1 X_test=np.reshape(X_test,(X_test.shape,X_test.shape[1], 1))
      2 predicted_closing_price=lstm_model.predict(X_test)
      3 predicted_closing_price=scaler.inverse_transform(predicted_closing_price)

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs on the first line. `X_test[1]` provokes the error as `X_test` is of dimension 1. In addition `.shape` returns a tuple while `np.reshape` requires a tuple of `int` as second positional argument.

This should solve the error:

```
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[0], 1))
```

Comment: I tried that too and the same error was coming up

Comment: What is the shape of X_test ?

Comment: You're correct that "`np.reshape` requires a tuple of `int` as second positional argument" but that's not the source of the error. the problem is that `X_test.shape` doesn't have a second dimention.